# Go, DER and handling big integers

Tags: encoding, go, digital-signature, biginteger, der

I want to create a Google Go application that will be able to DER encode and decode big integers (namely, [ECDSA signature r and s](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#Sign)). From what I understand I should use the [asn1 package](http://golang.org/pkg/asn1/), but what functions should I be calling?

For example, I want to encode

```
316eb3cad8b66fcf1494a6e6f9542c3555addbf337f04b62bf4758483fdc881d
```

and

```
bf46d26cef45d998a2cb5d2d0b8342d70973fa7c3c37ae72234696524b2bc812
```

to get this:

```
30450220316eb3cad8b66fcf1494a6e6f9542c3555addbf337f04b62bf4758483fdc881d022100bf46d26cef45d998a2cb5d2d0b8342d70973fa7c3c37ae72234696524b2bc81201
```

and vice versa. Which function should I call for encoding, and which for decoding and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode an ASN.1 sequence containing both r and s integers as follows:

```
ECDSA-Sig-Value ::= SEQUENCE {
  r INTEGER,
  s INTEGER }
```

Please note that I am not a Go developer but according to the documentation Marshal and Unmarshal functions seems to accept structs in order to encode/decode ASN.1 sequences.

This code sample seems to work for both encoding and decoding:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "big"
    "asn1"
)

type ecdsa struct {
    R, S *big.Int
}

func main() {
    r, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("316eb3cad8b66fcf1494a6e6f9542c3555addbf337f04b62bf4758483fdc881d", 16);
    s, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("bf46d26cef45d998a2cb5d2d0b8342d70973fa7c3c37ae72234696524b2bc812", 16);
    sequence := ecdsa{r, s}
    encoding, _ := asn1.Marshal(sequence)
    fmt.Println(encoding)
    dec := new(ecdsa)
    asn1.Unmarshal(encoding, dec)
    fmt.Println(dec)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the encoded message seems to be lacking the 01 byte at the end.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I did not notice this final "01" but I don't think this is correct ASN.1 DER encoding. The encoded message starts with "0x30 0x45": 0x30 is the Universal Tag SEQUENCE and 0x45 is the sequence length (tag & length excluded) ; if you read 69 bytes (0x45 in decimal) in the sequence you get all the data but the final "01".

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a byte specific to the implementation that encoding is used in. Already discussing that here - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/ecdsa-r-s-encoding-as-a-signature

Comment: As it turns out, the final 01 is a part of the implementation that DER is used in, not being part of the encoding itself, so your answer is correct.